# Zoo Visitor: confirm delete user account

Tags: zoo-visitor

In the 'member area' I have the ability for a user to delete their own user account, with a confirm password field.
Still, I would like to add an 'Are you sure?' Checkbox that is required.
Even better would be to have the user redirected to a confirmation page with an 'Are you sure?' button.
How would I accomplish this.

If I add rules:name_of_checkbox="required" to {exp:zoo_visitor:delete_form} it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following template that works perfectly using the stash plugin.

```
<!-- Delete -->
{if segment_3 == 'delete' AND !segment_4 AND "{exp:stash:get name='password' dynamic='yes'}" == '' AND "{exp:stash:get name='confirm_delete' dynamic='yes'}" == ''}

    <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{csrf_token}">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type='checkbox' name='confirm_delete' value='yes'>Are you shure?
    </form>

{if:elseif segment_3 == 'delete' AND !segment_4 AND "{exp:stash:get name='password' dynamic='yes'}" AND "{exp:stash:get name='confirm_delete' dynamic='yes'}" == 'yes'}

    {exp:zoo_visitor:delete_form
        return='/'
        role="form"
        include_jquery='no'
        datepicker='no'
        include_assets='no'
        secure_action='yes'
        secure_return='yes'
        require_password='yes'
    }
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="{exp:stash:get name='password' scope='user'}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-loading-text="Deleting Account...">Yes</button>
    {/exp:zoo_visitor:delete_form}

{if:else}

    {redirect='/account/edit/delete'}

{/if}
<!-- ./Delete -->
```